# how to get the least possible value of $m^{117} > 5^{78}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I find the smallest natural number $m$ where $m^{117} > 5^{78}$? And please tell me your complete answer.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The general way to do this is to apply the strictly monotone function $\sqrt[117]{\quad}$ (extraction of $117$th root) on both sides of the inequality symbol. You can also think of this as raising both sides of the inequality to the power of $\frac{1}{117}$. As you see from the answer, in this case you can "reduce" by $39$. You can also think of this as a simplification of the exponent fraction from $\frac{78}{117}$ to $\frac23$.

Answer (score 7):

Note that the equation is equivalent to proving that $(m^3)^{39}>(5^2)^{39}$.

Thus, the equation is equivalent to find the smallest $m$ so that there cube is greater than $25$. (Or Finding the smallest $m$ the $m^3>5^{2}$.

The least $m$ is $3$.